# WIX installer custom action using dll reference not project reference

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I have a WIX installer setup and working using a single custom action.  Right now I have the custom action referenced from the WIX project as a project reference. This does not work for my needs.  Is there a way to have the WIX setup project reference the output dll's and CA.dll without having the custom action as a second project.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'the custom action referenced from the WIX project as a project reference'?

Comment: Generally you'd just reference the custom action dlls directly in your WiX script as decribed in the documentation (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html)

Comment: is there a reason this was down voted

Comment: NGambit: when you have a solution in VS with multiple projects that all reference each other that is called a project reference.  If however you compile one of those sub libraries into a dll and just reference the dll directly this is a dll reference.  Not sure what what else to call it.

Comment: @NGambit: final note: your link to the extensions was exactly what I needed, thanks.  I had created a custom action following the tutorials on the WIX site, but missed the part were I could deploy it as a dll.

Comment: Okay, glad to help. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why creating a custom action project is an issue for you but maybe you could look into [WiX extensions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/extension_development_intro.html)

> WiX extensions are used to extend and customize what WiX builds and how it builds it.

You could [create a skeleton extension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/extension_development_simple_example.html) and use it to build your own custom action. You can then [author a binary custom action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html) in the WiX script